# vue router.push in nuxt using route.name

Tags: vue.js, parameters, nuxt.js, vue-router

I use nuxt and have following Problem. My old code looks like this:

```
this.$router.push({path: "about/me"})
```

Now I need to make the same call with some params:

```
this.$router.push({path: "about/me", params: {sendNotification: "1"}})
```

This obviously doesn't work since vue-router only allowes to use `params` with `name` and not `path`, so it has to look like:

```
  this.$router.push({name: ..., params: {sendNotification: "1"}})
```

I could do it with `query` instead of `params` but I don't want my url to look ugly.
The problem with nuxt is, or at least this is my understanding of nuxt, that it generates the route names using folder structure and in my case also the locale. So the name of this route is actually: "personal-about-me__en".

So my question: Is there a way to get the `route.name` dynamically, so I could write something like:

```
  this.$router.push({name: getRouteNameByPath("about/me"), params: {sendNotification: "true"}})
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of the route path is matching the `name` prop that you can give to the `.vue` file. So, write is as `name: 'AboutMe'` key property and use it in the router with `{ name: 'about-me' }`.

Also, vue devtools have a router tab with the name of all the available routes.

Answer (score 0):

> This obviously doesn't work since vue-router only allowes to use params with name and not path.

Why do you need to pass params alongside the path? You are supposed to add the params to the path itself, which is why vue-router doesn't allow a separate params object.

So for e.g. assuming your dynamic route is `about/me/:sendNotification`, you can either provide params with the named route:

```js
this.$router.push({name: ..., params: {sendNotification: "1"}});
```

which directs you to `about/me/1`.

OR you can push the entire path including the params

```js
this.$router.push({ path: 'about/me/1' });
```

Both will produce the exact same result.